# Pandas nested loop with a row matching a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, nested

What is the fastest way to iterate through the rest of a dataframe given rows matching some specific values ?

For example let's say I have a dataframe with 'Date', 'Name' and 'Movie'. There could be many users and movies. I want all the person named John that have seen the same movie as someone named Alicia has seen before.
Input dataframe could be :

```
                 date       name              movie
0 2018-01-16 10:33:59     Alicia            Titanic
1 2018-01-17 08:49:13   Chandler             Avatar
2 2018-01-18 09:29:09      Luigi              Glass
3 2018-01-19 09:45:27     Alicia           Die Hard
4 2018-01-20 10:08:05    Bouchra       Pulp Fiction
5 2018-01-26 10:21:47     Bariza              Glass
6 2018-01-27 10:15:32      Peggy         Bumbleblee
7 2018-01-20 10:08:05       John            Titanic
8 2018-01-26 10:21:47     Bariza              Glass
9 2018-01-27 10:15:32       John            Titanic
```

The result should be :

```
                 date       name              movie
0 2018-01-16 10:33:59     Alicia            Titanic
7 2018-01-20 10:08:05       John            Titanic
9 2018-01-27 10:15:32       John            Titanic
```

For the moment I am doing the following:

```
alicias = df[df['Name'] == 'Alicia']

df_res = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for i in alicias.index:
    df_res = df_res.append(alicias.loc[i], sort=False)

    df_johns = df[(df['Date'] > alicias['Date'][i])
                 &(df['Name'] == 'John')
                 &(df['Movie'] == alicias['Movie'][i)]

    df_res = df_res.append(df_johns, sort=False)
```

It works but this is very slow. I could also use a groupby which is much faster but I want the result to keep the initial row (the row with 'Alicia' in the example), and I can't find a way to do this with a groupby.

Any help ?

Comment: Please share a sample of the input dataframe

Comment: Sure. I mean for a dataframe sorted by date, if someone named Alicia has seen a movie at a certain date, output all the person that have seen the same movie after this date.

Comment: Can you show us your dataframe>

Comment: Also please provide more information. Is it only two users that are present in df?

Comment: Sorry if this is not very clear. I edited for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. Say you have the following dataframe:

```
     date      user    movie
0  2018-01-02  Alicia  Titanic
1  2018-01-13    John  Titanic
2  2018-01-22    John  Titanic
3  2018-04-02    John   Avatar
4  2018-04-05  Alicia   Avatar
5  2018-05-19    John   Avatar
```

IIUC the correct solution should not contain row 3, as `Alicia` had not seen `Avatar` yet. So you could do:

```
df[df.user.eq('Alicia').groupby(df.movie).cumsum()]

     date       user    movie
0  2018-01-02  Alicia  Titanic
1  2018-01-13    John  Titanic
2  2018-01-22    John  Titanic
4  2018-04-05  Alicia   Avatar
5  2018-05-19    John   Avatar
```

**Explanation:**

The following returns `True` where the `user` is `Alicia`:

```
df.user.eq('Alicia')

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: user, dtype: bool
```

What you could do now is to [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the movies, and apply a [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) on the groups, so only the rows after the first `True` will also become `True`:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: user, dtype: bool
```

Finally use `boolean indexation` on the original dataframe in order to select the rows of interest.

Comment: This is what I searched for but I will have never found this request on my own, thanks a lot!